# Bounty box is not aligned properly under the score value

Tags: bug, design, bounties

Bounty box is not aligned properly under the score value ([visible only for bounty offerer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46937593/3240681))

> [image: bounty box]

Tested in Firefox 65.0.1 and Chrome 72.0.3626.119 on Windows 7

Comment: Which browser do you have? I had the same problem with firefox, but in opera it looked ok

Comment: @user237989 added to the post.

Comment: This looks particularly ugly when you try to award a bounty to an answer which already received something. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfUtH.png